# MYSQL - Get data for every 5 mins and sum value from previous rows to show an aggregate data

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help on MySQL....I have the following query to pull data every 5 mins. But I need the revenue to be summed up to the previous hour as time progress and give final revenue at the end of the day. So each row revenue would be `sum of the revenue for that timestamp+previous hours total in the current row.`

```
SELECT o.creation_date,
       ROUND(SUM(((it.current_price*quantity)- IFNULL(it.total_adjustment,0))/100),0) AS reven,
       COUNT(o.order_id)
FROM order.order o
JOIN order.order_item it ON o.order_id=it.order_id
WHERE DATE(o.creation_date)='2014-09-16'
  AND o.order_status = "confirmed"
  AND it.line_item_type = 'item'
GROUP BY round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(o.creation_date)/300);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give you an sample to solve your main problem, assume you have an orders table with revenue in it like this:

```
create table orders
(creation_date datetime,
  reven decimal(20,2))
;

insert into orders (creation_date,reven)values
(curdate()+ INTERVAL 1 MINUTE ,100),
(curdate()+ INTERVAL 2 MINUTE ,100),
(curdate()+ INTERVAL 60 MINUTE ,100),
(curdate()+ INTERVAL 61 MINUTE ,100),
(curdate()+ INTERVAL 62 MINUTE ,100),
(curdate()+ INTERVAL 120 MINUTE ,100),
(curdate()+ INTERVAL 121 MINUTE ,100),
(curdate()+ INTERVAL 122 MINUTE ,100)
```

First step is to get all dates lead in five minutes(`lead_date`). Then join the orders table to within one hour of every `lead_date`.

```
select o1.lead_date,sum(reven) as reven
  from (select distinct FROM_UNIXTIME(round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_date)/300)*300) as lead_date
          from orders) o1
 inner join orders o2
    on o2.creation_date >= o1.lead_date
   and o2.creation_date < (o1.lead_date + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
 group by o1.lead_date
```

Here's the result:

```
LEAD_DATE                         REVEN
September, 18 2014 00:00:00+0000    200
September, 18 2014 01:00:00+0000    300
September, 18 2014 02:00:00+0000    300
```

I think you could apply this approach to your case, replace `revnen` to `(it.current_price*quantity)- IFNULL(it.total_adjustment,0)` , join your `order` and `order_item` tables as an subquery to replace `o2`.

Comment: Thank you,  I will try this today and will let you know